# Are these objects? Why do they look like that when I print them?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object, iteration

this is my first post and I'm quite new to programming/this site, so I apologise in advance if I'm doing something wrong/annoying.

I wanted to find a way to define objects without having to do so for each object. I came up with this

```
class Number
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def description
    puts "I'm #{@name} "
  end
end

a = ["zero", "one","two", "three", "four"]

for i in (0..5) do 
  a[i] = Number.new(a[i])
end

a[3].description
```

I'm hoping someone can tell me what kind of Frankensteins monster I've created?

It seems to work, a[3].description returns "I'm three" but does that mean three/a[3] exists as its own object and not an element of an array?

Furthermore if I try to do:

```
puts a[3]
```

I get:

```
<Context::Number:0x000000009b7fd0 @name="three">, #
```

To clarify I just want to know whether I have actually managed to create objects here, and why on earth when I try and access elements of my array I get that weird feedback (kind of seems like its accessing memory or something, but that is a little beyond me)

My thanks in advance for anyone who replies to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects stand on their own, regardless of whether they are contained by/in other objects such as Array instances.

Regarding this:

```
<Context::Number:0x000000009b7fd0 @name="three">, #
```

...did you mean you get that when you `puts a[3]` and not `puts a`?

Every instance of Object and its subclasses has a `to_s` method that returns a string representation of the object.  Since you did not override that in your Number class, it used the default implementation defined in class Object.  It is showing you:

1) the class name (I presume you defined Number in side a class or module named Context)

2) the object id (a unique id in the Ruby runtime)

3) the string representation of its instance variable(s)

Also, regarding this:

```
a = ["zero", "one","two", "three", "four"]
```

This is equivalent and easier to type (I use 2 spaces for better readability):

```
%w(zero  one  two  three  four)
```

Also, as Ilya pointed out, `map` will simplify your code.  I'll go a little further and recommend this to do the array initialization:

```
a = %w(zero  one  two  three  four).map { |s| Number.new(s) }
```

Comment: Yeah I did mean puts a[3]. Thanks btw that clears up quite a bit of my confusion! if I may ask a couple more questions? is there a reason why the object id would change every time I run the code? as that is what is happening each time I run and do 'puts a[3]' also, the code I pasted in my question was the entirety of what I've written; any idea how the class name became Context?

Comment: Object id's have no meaning in and of themselves (for example, they are not calculated based on the content of the object), and only exist as a value with which Ruby can identify the object in memory.  So there is no need or guarantee that they would be consistent across runs of your program.

Comment: Regarding `Context`, I have no idea...is this the only code in your file, and are you running the file directly on the command line, as in `ruby my_file.rb`?  If not, then how?

Comment: It's not the ID of the object. It's its memory address.

Comment: Ah ok, and I've figured out the 'context' thing; I fluctuate between using the command line via and codeacademy's console window ( like I said I'm new to programming ^_^ ) and the issue disappears when using cmd. Again, thank you for all the help, I can say my first experience with stackoverflow has been overwhelmingly positive

Comment: @cremno Yes, from the point of view of the Ruby runtime, object_id *is* the id of the object; and it is not necessarily the memory address.  Special objects in MRI Ruby have addresses that are not valid memory addresses (see http://thepaulrayner.com/blog/2013/02/06/object-ids-in-ruby/).  Furthermore, JRuby is Ruby too and I'm pretty sure JRuby object_id's are not physical memory addresses. In any case, I think the Rubyist should not assume any meaning other than 'a unique object id'. If it's a memory address it's for the convenience of the implementation only.

Comment: @KyranWilson I've added some idiomatic Ruby suggestion to the bottom of my answer.  Glad we helped you.

Comment: @cremno on MRI 3.2 the hex number is the object_id times 2.

Comment: @steenslag Please clarify?  What hex number?  Do you mean that the object_id is the memory address times 2?

Comment: I just think is your description is misleading. Yeah, there may be a correlation between this number and the object ID or it even may be the object ID but it usually isn't and one should not assume so.

Comment: At http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html, it says of to_s: "The default to_s prints the object’s class and an encoding of the object id." However, I just did a test in irb and found that the number printed by to_s was not the object id; try this in irb to prove you're right: `o = Object.new; puts o.to_s; puts o.object_id.to_s(16); nil` It was exactly as @steenslag said, the number in the to_s string was 2 times the object_id!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have created objects. It's just how Ruby represents a class as a string.

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :one, :two

  def initialize(one, two)
    @one, @two = one, two
  end
end

my_class = MyClass.new(1, 2)

my_class.to_s            # #<MyClass:0x007fcacb8c7c68>
my_class.inspect         # #<MyClass:0x007fcacb8c7c68 @one=1, @two=2>
```